# WorkManager vs Rxjava

Tags: java, android, rxjava

В чем разница между **WorkManager** и **Rxjava**? При каких обстоятельствах что использовать (примеры задач, пожалуйста)?

Comment: это разные вещи... work manager это комбо из сервисов, броадкастеров и прочей фоновой дичи в одном ключе для удобного использования. RxJava - анти колбэк

Answer (score 3):

Ну это как сравнить кухонную плиту и автомобиль.

- [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) - это инструмент который предоставляет API для планирования задач которые вы хотите выполнять с некоторым интервалом или в какое-то время.

  Например вы можете каждое утро запускать какой-то сервис которые будет обновлять данные с вашего API.
- [RX Java](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) - это огромный фрейворк который позволяет обрабатывать действия внутри приложения реактивно. Это очень трудно объяснить в одном ответе, так как по сути это целая парадигма в программировании. RX Java это про то как обрабатывать и изменять потоки данных как синхронно так и асинхронно.

  > Пользователи ожидают данных в реальном времени. Они хотят твиты
  > сейчас. Подтвержение заказа сейчас. Им необходимы цены по состоянию на
  > сейчас. Как разработчик, вы нуждаетесь в самонаводящихся сообщениях.
  > Вы не хотите быть блокированным в ожидании результата. Вы хотите,
  > чтобы результат пришел к вам по готовности. Даже более того, вы хотите
  > работать с результатом по частям: вы не хотите ждать пока загрузится
  > всё перед тем как отобразить первую строку. Мир перешел в режим
  > уведомлений. У разработчиков есть инструменты, чтобы уведомлять, это
  > легко. Им нужны инструменты чтобы реагировать на уведомления.

  Вот небольшая цитата из [статьи](https://habr.com/ru/post/269417/) о том какие проблемы решает RX Java

  Когда вы затягиваете RX Java в свой проект, то по сути она пронизывает его весь и вы пишете код в парадигме [реактивного программирования](https://habr.com/ru/company/2gis/blog/228125/). Вы ходите в сеть с помощью RX, вы делаете запросы в базу данных с помощью RX, вы фильтруете, обрабатываете и вообще производите все возможные действия с помощью RX. А некоторые даже события UI обрабатывают с помощью RX.

Первое это просто инструмент для узкого круга задач, второе это подход к программированию реализованный в большой библиотеке.